sqlalchemy - how to get attributes from the query response into an object
I am trying to get the some calculated value from a sqlquery into the object that should be instantiated, however access to those values seems impossible.
given three tables:  A, B, A_to_B

A - some model

somevalues
"totalsum"


B - some model
A_to_B - assocication table with extra values

a_id
b_id
count



I need to do a query like
select a.*, sum(a_to_b.count) as totalsum from A, A_to_B where a.id=A_to_B.a_id;

and other variations...
sqlalchemy throws an error
Label name totalsum is being renamed to an anonymous label due to disambiguation which is not supported right now.  Please use unique names for explicit labels

is there any way to get sqlalchemy to bind the values of the associationtable to a model ?
thanks in advance!

The error is pretty clear as 'totalsum' is present in table A just alias the sum(a_to_b.count) to something else e.g. 'total_sum'

yes the error is clear... it is however totally unclear how to resolve it and stiil get the info into the object. just aliasing it to something else wont cause the value to end up in my model.

The problem is why are you selecting a.totatsum as well, how will you manage 2 values with same name. Can't you select values that you need from table A and not a.*.  This is a fundamental issue that your model is getting 2 values with same name.

Does A.totalsum actually contain any values or is it just a placeholder for the sum of the values in A_to_B?

its just a placeholder..

try to use aliased or explicit labels
use explicit labels with unique names to avoid conflicts. SQLAlchemys label function allows you to define custom labels. Here is how you can adjust your query:
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
from sqlalchemy import func, label

totalsum = func.sum(A_to_B.count).label('totalsum')

query = (
session.query(A, totalsum)
.join(A_to_B, A.id == A_to_B.a_id)
.group_by(A.id))

results = query.all()


thank you - that returns the desired column as a separate row.
however it does not set is as an attribute of model A.
the only way i could get it to be in there is by "manually"  adding it when processing the rows of .all()...

I still could not solve the problem stated in the question nicely although i suspect this must be possible in a proper sqlalchemy-fashion, since this is a standard use-case in many-to-many setups.
however, it is possible to solve with a manual step involved ..
stmt = select(A, func.sum(A_to_B.count).label('totalsum'))
  .join(A_to_B, A.id == A_to_B.a_id)
  .group_by(A.id))

rows = (await sess.execute(stmt)).all()
for r in rows:
  r[0].totalsum = r[1]

model A must not have the "totalsum" column in this case defined in the model. we're just adding that attribute "on-the-fly" for further use.
